# MySql Loop through a column to form concatenated string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to SQL and PHP. I have a requirement where the end user enters text in an HTML form, which I am storing in MySQL db. Later I query all the tables in the db which has the user data to obtain concatenated strings.

For a clearer understanding here is an image of my data and the desired result: [Click for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjTbP.png)

[image]

Right now I am able to concatenate only one string based on a specific id with this query:

```
select group_concat(text order by T.did separator ' ') as TTT 
from (
  select l.dimgroupid as did, d.*,  l.dimlevelid as id, l.dimlevelvalue,
     concat(d.dimensiontext," ",l.dimlevelvalue) as text 
  from dimensionlevel l 
  join dimension d on d.dimensionid = l.dimid
  join dimensiongroup g on g.groupid = l.dimgroupid) as T 
where T.id=0;
```

which gives me the result

```
| TTT                          | 
--------------------------------
| A 20 year old Man is Fresher |
```

I know I can use a loop on id, but the problem is the ids are not fixed.

Note: There can be "n" number of dimensions and levels.

Here is an SQL Fiddle of the data I am trying to query: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa366/81)

Comment: I don't think you can do this in an sql-query. There is no number(s) that identifies all elements of a sentence, so you cannot use `group by`, and with an unlimited number of dimensions (sentence length), you cannot use `join`. And the resultset might get quite big quite fast. Also I doubt you can currently get all sentences with your current query by just changing your id (and it's missing an order I think). But you should be able to do it relatively easily in php, as you can simply loop through all the groups, levels and ids there, without having to know how many there will be beforehand.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I was also thinking the same as Dimensions and levels are not fixed its hard to get the output. I will let you know if I am able to pull it off using PHP.

Comment: Just for completeness: you can of course use loops in mysql too (e.g. in a stored procedure), you don't have to do them in php. It would require you to create the (potentially large) result in a (temporary) table by joining the data with itself for every level. If your intention is to have the data in an actual table, this might be a proper solution. Also you can use dynamic sql (that builds the joins using a a loop) both in php or mysql. Also other databases (like postgres) are able to to this (as they support recursion). But (I still think) you can't do it in a single normal query in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your query to get what you wanted..

```
    select did as groupid, group_concat(text order by dimensionid separator ' ' ) as TTT
    from ( 
           select l.dimgroupid as did, d.*,  l.dimlevelid as id, l.dimlevelvalue, concat(d.dimensiontext," ",l.dimlevelvalue) as text
           from dimensionlevel l 
           join dimension d on d.dimensionid = l.dimid
           join dimensiongroup g on g.groupid = l.dimgroupid
         ) as T
    group by id;
```

I hope this helps you...

UPDATE :
using php..

```
$sql = "SELECT `dimensionid`, `dimensiontext`, `dimensiondescr` FROM `dimension`";
$dimensions = mysqli_fetch_all (mysqli_query($con, $sql));

$sql = "SELECT `dimlevelvalue` FROM `dimensionlevel` WHERE dimid IN (SELECT dimensionid FROM dimension WHERE dimensiondescr='age') ";
$ages = mysqli_fetch_all (mysqli_query($con, $sql));

$sql = "SELECT `dimlevelvalue` FROM `dimensionlevel` WHERE dimid IN (SELECT dimensionid FROM dimension WHERE dimensiondescr='sex') ";
$sexes = mysqli_fetch_all (mysqli_query($con, $sql));

$sql = "SELECT `dimlevelvalue` FROM `dimensionlevel` WHERE dimid IN (SELECT dimensionid FROM dimension WHERE dimensiondescr='experience') ";
$experiences = mysqli_fetch_all (mysqli_query($con, $sql));

foreach ($ages as $age) {
    foreach ($sexes as $sex) {
        foreach ($experiences as $exp) {

            foreach ($dimensions as $dimension) {
                $putage = "";
                $putsex = "";
                $putexp = "";
                if($dimension[2]=="Age"){
                    $putage = $age[0];
                }elseif($dimension[2]=="Sex"){
                    $putsex = $sex[0];
                }elseif($dimension[2]=="Experience"){
                    $putexp = $exp[0];
                }
                echo $str = $dimension['1']." ".$putage.$putsex.$putexp." " ;
            }
            echo "<br>";
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yea i need in that format but i need all the combinations as shown in the image. It is not a fixed set. I need all possibilities. Refer the final output table from the image to get an idea of what I am talking about.